# How do I intergrate PayPal with a PHP system in this specific way?

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment

I have a system that simply registers a user. I need to intergrate this with PayPal so that only IF a user has paid can they have access their account. Paying involves confirming to a monthly payment, with the first month free. I need to use some PayPal API that will inform the user of the monthly fee, let's them subscribe, and then if it was a successful returns True to my PHP system so It can then activate the account.

So what do I need to do to get this process running? What will I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.paypal.com/ is a great place to start.

They offer guides and code libraries and examples there.

And as far your rest of the requirement, you can handle that in `callback from paypal.` according to payment status and update your record and notify the user.

1. You need a Form from Where you post information to Paypal (which you can find in paypal SDK
2. Paypal Will process the payment once form correctly posted.
3. Paypal will send you response on your callback.php file of which file link you post in Form.
4. Handle all your conditions in that callback file.

Comment: I havnt been able to find specific code and actually linking the API with PHP...? It just goes over principals, etc

Comment: paypal has all the example code in there SDK, choose which you need and play with it, set a sandbox account on paypal to check payment statues without making real payment and handle everything else in callback file,